# Can't send document files from pi to my phone or laptop on bluetooth (it is showing up as audio)

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, connection, debian

Running Debian version 12 on a Pi4B.

My pi is my typewriter, and I want to send document (WordGrinder) files from the pi to my Pixel phone (or laptop) over bluetooth. I have a strong bluetooth connection with both those devices, and I have an option on the pi Bluetooth Devices window (in the GUI) to Send File.

From both my laptop and phone, I am successful in sending a file *to* the Pi - it is received on the Pi end and placed in Downloads.

However, I cannot successfully send from the Pi over bluetooth. I am using the GUI Bluetooth Devices window to try to send files - it has a "Send Files" button.

When I try to send to the Pixel phone from that window I get from blueman-sendto "Error occurred while sending file

When I try to send to the laptop I get error from blueman-sendto that says "Error occurred Unable to find service record"

I've already failed utterly in getting these devices to find my Pi wifi Access Point, so bluetooth is my last option. I'm not highly technical but I can function in the command line, if you speak slowly. I would appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: Let me add that both the phone and the laptop see the Pi as an audio device. On the laptop it shows "connected mic, audio" and the pixel phone also sees it as audio.

Comment: This likely has to do with what the pi presented itself as.  If you configure it to, it could show up as a game controller or keyboard.  If you have a pi and are having difficulty getting access, I suggest enabling ssh and using a wired connection.

Comment: Thanks - Is there a way for me to edit what the Pi is presenting itself as? I can use ssh over wifi from the phone/laptop/pi when the Pi is connected to the home wifi system. I am trying to arrange it so I can do the file transfers when I'm camping away from an external wifi. If I can't  get wifi or bluetooth working then I guess USB is my only option, but wireless would be very nice.

Comment: While most solutions will be for a rpi os (not straight forward debian), you can likely port some of the needed packages.  I suggest you google something like "how to transfer files by bluetooth from a raspberry pi"

Comment: Thanks. I actually did google it quite a bit before posting here for help, but I'll get back to it. If I solve it I will post back here in case anyone else has trouble.